# Why is Context needed for getRelativeTimeSpanString?

Tags: java, android

I was wondering why [`getRelativeTimeSpanString`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/format/DateUtils.html#getRelativeTimeSpanString%28android.content.Context,%20long,%20boolean%29) needs a context? (leaving the puns aside)

```
public static CharSequence getRelativeTimeSpanString (Context c, long millis, boolean withPreposition)
```

Comment: To choose the language/format to respond in? (According to your locale)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look through the source code:

```
public static CharSequence getRelativeTimeSpanString(Context c, long millis,
        boolean withPreposition) {

    long now = System.currentTimeMillis();
    long span = now - millis;

    if (sNowTime == null) {
        sNowTime = new Time();
        sThenTime = new Time();
    }

    sNowTime.set(now);
    sThenTime.set(millis);

    String result;
    int prepositionId;
    if (span < DAY_IN_MILLIS && sNowTime.weekDay == sThenTime.weekDay) {
        // Same day
        int flags = FORMAT_SHOW_TIME;
        result = formatDateRange(c, millis, millis, flags);
        prepositionId = R.string.preposition_for_time;
    } else if (sNowTime.year != sThenTime.year) {
        // Different years
        int flags = FORMAT_SHOW_DATE | FORMAT_SHOW_YEAR | FORMAT_NUMERIC_DATE;
        result = formatDateRange(c, millis, millis, flags);

        // This is a date (like "10/31/2008" so use the date preposition)
        prepositionId = R.string.preposition_for_date;
    } else {
        // Default
        int flags = FORMAT_SHOW_DATE | FORMAT_ABBREV_MONTH;
        result = formatDateRange(c, millis, millis, flags);
        prepositionId = R.string.preposition_for_date;
    }
    if (withPreposition) {
        Resources res = c.getResources();
        result = res.getString(prepositionId, result);
    }
    return result;
}
```